# PHP pattern match to identify a specific string with a number in

Tags: php, regex

I am putting "merge" fields in my text, ie:

::sub_menu::33::

I want to be able to find all occurrences of this pattern:

::sub_menu::(any number)::

Then I'll go on to extract the number and replace it (I don't need help with that bit thanks).

I've used preg_match_all before, but am not sure how to use it when I want to use a specific string as part of the match? Any help much apprciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to find all occurrences of this pattern: `::sub_menu::(any number)::`

You can use this regex:

```
/::sub_menu::\(\d+\)::/
```

To use it in `preg_match_all` use:

```
if ( preg_match_all('/::sub_menu::\((\d+)\)::/', $input, $match) )
    print_r($match[0]);
```

Comment: I think he is asking how to use preg_match_all not how to construct regex.

Comment: Thanks! This worked:

preg_match_all('/::sub_menu::(\d+)::/', $str_content, $matches);

Comment: Short and sweet, +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
preg_match("/::sub_menu::\((\d+)\)::/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

The $output_array for an input of *::sub_menu::(33)::* will contain:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ::sub_menu::(33)::
    [1] => 33
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I didn't actually mean ( ) to be part of the pattern, so the first answer did work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

$input = '::sub_menu::33::';

```
/* if you have one or more numbers,  use (+) quantifiers*/ 
if ( preg_match('/::sub_menu::[0-9]+::/', $input, $match) )


/* if you want to put min/max quantifiers min by 2 and max by 10*/
if ( preg_match('/::sub_menu::[0-9]{2,10}::/', $input, $match) ){

    print_r($match);

}
```